# Kotlin collect SharedFlow is not collecting

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Let us say I have a class that emits a flow, and a function in another class that collects it:

> THIS WORKS
>
> ```
> class DebugMessage {
>    val sharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<String>()
>
>    fun makeFlow() {
>        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
>            for (i in 0 until 10) {
>                sharedFlow.emit(Random.nextInt(1,100).toString())
>                delay(200)
>            }
>        }
>    }
>
>    fun getFlow(): Flow<String> {
>        makeFlow()
>        return sharedFlow
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> And
>
> ```
> private fun collectDebugMsg() {
>    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
>        val getFlow = DebugMessage().getFlow()
>        getFlow.collect { Timber.d("VALUE IS $it") }
>    }
> }
> ```

This works as expected but is a bit useless. I need to split up the `makeFlow` and the `getFlow` functions. I would first call the `makeFlow` function and then the `getFlow` function So that would be for example:

> THIS DOES NOT WORK
>
> ```
> class DebugMessage {
>    val sharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<String>()
>
>    fun makeFlow() {
>        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
>            for (i in 0 until 10) {
>                sharedFlow.emit(Random.nextInt(1,100).toString())
>                delay(200)
>            }
>        }
>    }
>
>    fun getFlow(): Flow<String> {
>        //makeFlow() // Call 'makeFlow' from outside the DebugMessage Class
>        return sharedFlow
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> And
>
> ```
> private fun collectDebugMsg() {
>    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
>        DebugMessage().makeFlow() // Call 'makeFlow' from outside the DebugMessage Class
>        val getFlow = DebugMessage().getFlow()
>        getFlow.collect { Timber.d("VALUE IS $it") }
>    }
> }
> ```

The flow is no longer collecting anything. Anybody an idea why that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each call to `DebugMessage()` creates a new, distinct instance of the `DebugMessage` class. `DebugMessage().makeFlow()` creates one instance and "activates" it, then `DebugMessage().getFlow()` creates another instance and collects its flow while still not activated. To fix the problem you have to collect from the same instance that you activated:

```kotlin
val debugMessage = DebugMessage()
debugMessage.makeFlow()
val getFlow = debugMessage.getFlow()
```